# Run javascript function after Server-Side validation is complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

Ok, I've got a lightbox with a small form (2 fields) in it, inside an UpdatePanel, and I want to close this lightbox (must be done via javascript) when the 'Save' button is pressed.

However, there is a need to have a server-side CustomValidator on the page, and I only want to close the lightbox if this returns as valid.

Does anyone know a way to trigger javascript (or jQuery) code from a server-side validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a little snippet of code using the `ScriptManager` to execute after the response comes back to the `UpdatePanel`.

```
if (Page.IsValid){

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            customValidator1, 
            typeof(MyPageClass), 
            "closeBox",
            "myLightBoxVariableOnThePage.close()",
            true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When that server side validator runs, it will send a *whole new page* to the browser.  Anything that was shown in the browser before was *destroyed*, including any state kept in your javascript.  If new page bears a strong resemblance to the old page, you should consider this a happy coincidence.

Therefore, the thing to do here is rather than executing a javascript function, have your CustomValidator make the correct changes to the page on success so that it's rendered to the browser correctly in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lightbox simply will not work like that, it's a jQuery lightbox (built on top of FaceBox) which cannot be left open after a postback without removing it from the updatepanel context. It's complex, hence my need to run some javascript code when valid, as opposed to just making the lightbox invisible or something.